# Including headers just for private data in a .h file

Tags: c++, include, header-files

I have a class defined in `class.cpp` and `class.h`. The class uses some structures/classes/types/whatever defined in `stuff.h` (and of course, `stuff.cpp`) for private members and methods. My main program is in `main.cpp`, which `#include`s `class.h`, but doesn't care about anything in `stuff.h`. If it makes a difference, `class.cp` is supposed to be loaded dynamically (.dll/.so).
I would ideally like to have the `stuff.h` only included in `class.cpp` and `stuff.cpp` linked only to this file, as they would just cause name-space pollution in `main.cpp` and extra bloat by being linked to the final program.
The problem is that I have to include `stuff.h` in `class.h`, since it's definitions are used in the `private:` part of my class, which is all in `class.h`. And since `main.cpp` brings in `class.h`, it also gets `stuff.h`!

I hope this was clear. In C# this can be solved by partial classes. How would I do this in C++?

Comment: Are you worried about the symbols of `stuff.h` being included to `main.cpp`, or the actual definition? Meaning - if you only have forward declarations of the symbols from `stuff.h`, will it still cause problems in `main.cpp`?

Comment: @eli-iser What are forward declarations?

Comment: As described by Soren and ks1322 - if you have `class Stuff`, you can use it in `class.h` without `#include`ing `stuff.h` by using forward deceleration - `class Stuff;`. This will enalbe `class.h` to recognize the class `Stuff` without the `#include`.

Comment: @eli-iser But wont that still end up in `main.cpp`?

Comment: @baruch -- look at the wikipedia link in my answer below -- it provide a C++, cut-n-paste example on how to do it all.

Comment: Yes - `main.cpp` will have the forward declaration of `Stuff`, but it won't be able to use it because it doesn't have the full definition (provided by `stuff.h`). If what you want is that `main.cpp` will not know nothing about `stuff.h`, then forward declaration won't help you. That was what I was asking.

Comment: @baruch -- what ends up in the different compilation units is the subject for a different question of how to make .so and .ddl files.  Ultimately that is a question of linker options rather than how header files, private data, and implementation hiding.  If you accept an answer you stand a better chance of somebody helping you with that particular question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do that in C++ by using pImpl [aka Opaque Pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) where the class you expose only have one attribute which is a partially defined struct (sometimes people uses void* instead, but to same efefct).

The partially defined struct, then is fully defined inside your `stuff.cpp` and everything works as you expect -- the only snag is that you need to make sure that you constructor and destructor new/delete the internal implementation, and you need to make special provisions in your copy constructor and and your assignment operator `operator=` -- most people opt for just make the copy constrctor and assignment operators private, so that the compiler will object if they are used.

Comment: You can also do pimpl with smart pointers and get rid of trouble with construction/destruction of the private implementation.

Comment: @Marthinho, Interesting suggestion, do you have an example which could be referenced?

Comment: There's an example in the boost docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#pimpl (btw that page is full of other gems.)

Comment: The fact that the `struct` is defined as `private` makes `main.cpp` completely ignorant of if?

Comment: It is not defined at all in any other sense than as a type-name, so it does not really matter at all to main.cpp -- it does not know any of the attributes, or any of the operators which works on it -- main.cpp can only create a pointer to the struct and nothing else, and the fact that it is defined inside the class means that your namespace is not polluted either

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need [Pimpl Idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) here. The main idea of Pimpl is that you forward declare class with implementation instead of including it's definition. This allows you to remove dependencies on implementation in header files, which usually results in compilation speed up, especially on large projects.